# Formula to convert a cell formatted in MM/DD/YYYY , to numeric month.

Tags: excel-formula

Is it possible to convert the standard excel format (MM/DD/YYYY) to just the month? I have column B that has a date format &column V where I have the month. I have check the internet/stack overflow, but have only found conversions for changing the format of the date.

Comment: (FYI - literally the [first hit on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=get%20month%20from%20date%20excel) solves your problem)

Comment: @macro man. Thanks. I don't know how I missed that. I guess wording  This does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean like the MONTH() formula?:

```
=MONTH(B1)
```

Comment: ie.  Row 3 Column B shows 11/4/2015. What I am trying to get is  the numeric number 11, with out the 4/2015. I just realized that I was not very clear. Hopefully this makes the question clearer.

Comment: I apologize to the group. I guess that I am having a Monday  problem.

Comment: @FrankM no need to apologise - if you have learnt something then the site has served it's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If the date is stored as an excel serial, to display just the month without losing the potential other information such as year, day, and time that might be stored with it, you are usually better off reformatting the display of the cell.

If you set the format of the cells to General and the numbers change you know you have your date in an Excel format.  If they do not change you have them as a string.

Select custom format for the cell format and go to the area when your can type in display formats and set it either to

```
m or mm - for numbers to be displayed.  The later will give you a proceeding 0 for single digit months.

mmm - for the first three letters of the month.

mmmm - for the full spelling of the month.
```

If you need to make comparisons of the month from a full date, use the formula macro man listed in a manner like:

```
=Month(B1)=Month(V1)
```

That will display true if the months for the dates in both A1 and V1 are the same.